# Redux+Websockets: Why manage this using middleware?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, redux

I've been reading about the best way to integrate WebSockets into a React/Redux app, and I'm finding answers but with some sentence along the lines of "The best place for websocket implementation is usually middleware."

My question is WHY this is preferred? What is the benefit of doing this vs setting up the websocket/having listeners dispatch actions in the outer App-level React container (in `componentWillMount` for instance)?

This seems like it would be equivalent in terms of lasting throughout the lifecycle of the app, etc. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are couple of pros with placing such logic in middle-wares instead of actual components.
The main reasons in my opinion are:

- Each connected component will instantiate a `WebSocket` or you will
  need a global declaration of the connection which will be
  independently from the store, in other words, not part of the `redux`
  flow.
- Middle-Wares have access to the store and are part of the `redux`
  flow.
- You also get access to the **entire** store, hence you can pass
  forward more data then initially dispatched.
- You decouple the components from the web-socket logic, hence you can
  centralize your code and reuse your components.

All in all, there are no special reasons that are specific regarding using web-sockets with middle-wares, using middle-wares have great advantages in general.

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment

> How would you suggest managing a case where you might want a
>   particular component to initialize a websocket connection, but want to
>   manage whether it's already connected, etc... would it be just as
>   simple as having a flag in the store that says it's connected or is
>   there a better approach?

As i said, I wouldn't initialize a web-socket connection within a component, rather I would do it in the entry point of my application. like `index.js` for example.
If your concern is to make sure you won't try to connect when there is already a connection, then a simple *`socketStart`* method that get invoked at the point when you create the `store` and initialize all your App data, you can pass it a callback that will do the rendering and `store` update through `dispatch`.
A simple example (keep in mind this is a pseudo code ):

**Our Socket-start Method:**

```
export function socketStart(store, callback) {
  // this is only a pseudo code!

  // register to server -> client events
  _socketClient.someFunction = (data) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: "Server_Invoked_Some_Function", data });
  }

  _socketClient.someFunction2 = (data) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: "Server_Invoked_Some_Function2", data });
  }

  // connect to the server via the web-socket client API
  _socketClient.connect(() => callback());
}
```

**We can use it in our `index.js` file:**

```
let store = createStore(
  // your reducers here...
  // ...
  applyMiddleware(socketMiddleware) // our web socket middleware
)

// the callback will invoked only if the connection was successful
// the React-Dom's render function is our callback in this case
socketStart(store, () => { render(<App />, document.getElementById("root")); });
```

Comment: That all makes sense, thanks!  The biggest reason here seems to be that as middleware, it will have access to the whole store, which wouldn't be available (or would be strange/architecturally weird) to connect using a top-level component.

How would you suggest managing a case where you might want a particular component to initialize a websocket connection, but want to manage whether it's already connected, etc... would it be just as simple as having a flag in the store that says it's connected or is there a better approach?

Comment: First of all i wouldn't initialize a websocket connection within a component but do it in the entry point of my application (like `index.js` for example). if your concern is to make sure you won't try to connect when theres already a connection then a simple connection method that invoked when you create the `store`  and in its callback you can render the app. i will update the answer with a simple example

Answer (score 1):

With middleware, you can easily unfold/relay messages between Redux and Web Socket. Also, you can use Redux middleware without React, that means you can write API using Redux on server-side code (probably with Redux saga).

I would agree lifetime management as a React component is easier than a Redux middleware. But if you want to reconnect (destroy/recreate), you will need to use `key` props to make the reconciler to consider it as a new object, which is a little bit weird.

You can look at [`redux-websocket-bridge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-websocket-bridge), which unfold Web Socket messages into Redux actions, and relay Redux actions to Web Socket.

On your Web Socket server, you send an action:

```
ws.on('connection', conn => {
  conn.send(JSON.stringify({ 
    type: 'GREETING', 
    payload: { now: Date.now() } 
  }));
});
```

You will get the `GREETING` action on your Redux reducer. And vice versa, when you want to relay an action to Web Socket, you mark your action with `meta.send` with `true`:

```
this.props.dispatch({ 
  type: 'SIGN_IN',
  meta: { send: true },
  payload: { authToken: '...' }
});
```